# Filter dataframe using values from a column

Tags: python, pandas, search, filter

I have a dataframe containing the employee name, employee email, manager name and manager email. I need to filter this dataframe using all the unique values of the manager email and confirm they also appear in the column employee email, this way making sure they are also in the database as an employee.

For example I have this dataframe:

```
Employee Name            Employee E-mail            Manager Name            Manager E-mail
Pedro                    pedro@gmail.com            Paul                    paul@gmail.com
Paul                     N/A                        Carlos                  carlos@gmail.com
Richard                  richard@gmail.com          Josh                    josh@gmail.com
Carlos                   carlos@gmail.com           Peter                   #
Maria                    #                          Bob                     N/A
Josh                     josh@gmail.com             Carlos                  carlos@gmail.com
```

This would return the following dataframe:

```
Employee Name            Employee E-mail            Manager Name            Manager E-mail
Richard                  richard@gmail.com          Josh                    josh@gmail.com
Josh                     josh@gmail.com             Carlos                  carlos@gmail.com
```

What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use masks and boolean indexing:

```
# is the employee email valid? you can use a different pattern e.g. '@company\.com'
m1 = df['Employee E-mail'].str.contains('@').fillna(False)
# is the manager email valid?
m2 = df['Manager E-mail'].str.contains('@').fillna(False)
# is the manager also an employee?
m3 = df['Manager E-mail'].isin(df['Employee E-mail'])

# all conditions True
df2 = df.loc[m1&m2&m3]
```

output:

```
  Employee Name    Employee E-mail Manager Name    Manager E-mail
2       Richard  richard@gmail.com         Josh    josh@gmail.com
5          Josh     josh@gmail.com       Carlos  carlos@gmail.com
```